# MySQL query result pipelining

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I type `SHOW tables` then result as below

`+----------------------------+
| Tables_in_sakila           |
+----------------------------+
| actor                      |
| actor_info                 |
| address                    |
| category                   |
| city                       |
| country                    |
| customer                   |
| customer_list              |
| film                       |
| film_actor                 |
| film_category              |
| film_list                  |
| film_text                  |
| inventory                  |
| language                   |
| nicer_but_slower_film_list |
| payment                    |
| rental                     |
| sales_by_film_category     |
| sales_by_store             |
| staff                      |
| staff_list                 |
| store                      |
+----------------------------+`

And I wanna pipe to DESC each item.

like DESC actor, DESC actor_info, DESC address, ... ,

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean "pipe" them? You can't do what you're asking for in a single query. You'd need to involve another secondary language to parse the list, and execute describe queries for each.

Comment: @FrankerZ umm.. I meant pipelining like linux |. I wanna DESC each item of SHOW TABLES result

Comment: do you want to get these table name in descending order ?? than i can help you in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get table name in descending order then you can get in following
manner

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema ='test'
ORDER BY table_name desc
```